# When ACK lost, both sender and receiver stop?

Tags: c, sockets

I am implementing a **UDP-based Stop-and-Wait ARQ**. I am trying to **simulate an error probability.**

In both sender and receiver, I have a `while()` loop to keep sending and receiving going. Everything works until I introduce an error probability on the receiver side.

I on purpose make the receiver not send `ACK` even if it has received the packet (to simulate the cases where `ACK` is lost).

What surprises me is that **both the sender and receiver hang**! I know this because to debug I put a `printf()` in both the sender's and the receiver's `while` loop and nothing is printed.

Why will this happen? Even if nothing is transmitted, the `while` loop (independent of `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`) should not stop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you have `recvfrom` in both the sender and receiver while loops.

The [recvfrom](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) documentation says:

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking.

To make a socket nonblocking see the documentation about the MSG_DONTWAIT flag.

So, I'm guessing that when you have the receiver not send your acknowledge message, the sender is just stopping and waiting on the recvfrom function and the receiver is hanging on its own recvfrom function the 2nd time through the while loop after omitting the acknowledge message (both the sender and receiver are using the blocking function recvfrom, 1 of them needs to be sending a message).

Comment: Wow exactly! I proved your statement by gdb it, it indeed gets stuck at recvfrom. But I wonder how are we gonna implement the timeout, if it is like so?

Comment: My guess is you could make the recvfrom function non-blocking with the MSG_DONTWAIT flag and then put the if ... TIMEOUT code section into some sort of while loop. Put the recvfrom call in this new timeout loop, since it is nonblocking the while loop will just keep looping checking if it can receive a message. Once the timeout has expired you could take the appropriate actions of re-transmitting or whatever you want. Not sure it'll work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Awesome! I made it. Thanks:)

Comment: You might want to keep your code examples in the question so this post is helpful to other users...